# Handling posting state in client

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile

This is more of a general question on how to design/implement `POST` operation in the client app, especially when it is a mobile app.

Whatever the thing is you are `POST`ing to the server, such as a blog post if you are building a blog, a chat message if chat app, a tweet if Twitter, you want to know whether the operation went successfully or not.

Let's take a twitter example.

The basic requirements are below:

1. When you post a tweet, the tweet shows up as `sending` state in the timeline before the operation ends. Most common way to show as a view is to make the tweet blur.
2. Once the operation went successfully, say the tweet is made and visible to all the followers, the tweet becomes solid color and let the user know the tweet is live.
3. If the operation didn't succeed, the tweet is shown with a red `!` mark and tell the user this tweet failed to post and they can retry tweeting it later.

This is done easily by having 3 different states, `POSTING` & `SUCCESS` & `FAIL`, and switch back and forth by checking status code from the server.

My question is how can we handle the case when the user closed the app(in the background) right after tweeting? In a naive implementation, we will not be able to get a status code from the server and keep having a state `POSTING`.

Is there any best practices to make this easy to handle?

Answer (score 1):

There's several things you can do:

1)Send a push notification that the post is finished.  This would wake the receiver up and allow you to update the status.

OR

2)When your app is started, query the server for those items in the POSTING state and see if they completed or not.

These actually aren't mutually exclusive, as 2 would be a fail safe for a push message that somehow got lost.

Comment: Thanks! I'm a bit confused with the approach 1. Does a push notification boot up the listener even if the app is in the background?